# Verify site ownership in google for Gitbook site

Tags: google-search-console, gitbook

How to do the google verification ownership site in [Gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/), to do for example, the sitemap's uploading to Google?

Google explains many techniques. Apparently the easiest one is to upload an HTML file into the main folder page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en

The problem is gitbook doesn't upload files in such a way: `www.mygitbooksite.com/googleVerificacion4341321.html`. But is possible to add in a folder: `www.mygitbooksite.com/someFolder/googleVerificacion4341321.html`

I found a gitbook plugin which can be related to the solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-verifications

I searched a lot but no luck in doing this verification, only in how to add google analytics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I found a way to validate the site via the **HTML meta tag**:

Install the plugin [gitbook-plugin-meta-single](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-meta-single), and then edit the `book.json` file:

```
  "pluginsConfig": {
        "meta-single": {
            "name": "google-site-verification",
            "content": "here the key string provided by google"
        }
    }
```

It will add the key inside `<HEAD>` tag

```
 <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Your Title</TITLE>
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="here the key string provided by google">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
```

Click on **Verify** button in google page, so they can re-check the authentication. And that's it!

Comment: Any idea on how to do this on the hosted free version of gitbook?